# Rails nested routing depending on current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, routes

I am trying to make a reservation application which will allow users to make account and then book a reservation but people who haven't made an account should also be able to book a reservation.

So far I have a User, Reservation, and Order models. I've made a one-to-one association between reservation and order. As of right now my routes.rb is as such:

```
resources :reservations do
 resources :orders
end
```

This association is working fine right now in my application. I'm also able to create a user in my application and have them logged in but I have not joined these two yet.

I know that I have to have a one-to-many relationship between User and Reservation that 'has_one' Order but where I'm having trouble moving forward is trying to think how I can add the User resource so that it doesn't matter whether a visitor to the application has an account or not. I'm not sure how the controllers and routes would be if I were to go in that direction.

If I add the following to my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
 resources :reservations do
  resources :orders
 end
end
```

I feel I would always have to have a user to create a reservation. Not sure how to go about it if the user is not signed in or doesn't have an account.

I've tried searching for a solution but I have not come across anything that seems like it would be helpful in my case.

Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you can explain what you are trying to achieve, then we could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a user to create a reservation, you don't want to nest `/reservations` under `/users` - doing that requires a `:user_id` in the path, which clearly you don't have. Just leave both at the top level:

```
resources :users
resources :reservations
```

Your user can still have many reservations, even if the URL doesn't completely mirror that (and with all of users, reservations, and orders, your paths are getting pretty deep). If you'd like a user-specific reservation index, you can still add a *second* route nested under users the way you already have:

```
resources :users do
  resources :reservations
end

resources :reservations
```

Then your application will respond to both `/reservations` and `/users/:user_id/reservations`, and the logic in your `ReservationsController` can apply `params[:user_id]` if it's present:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    scope = Reservation
    scope = scope.where(user_id: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    @reservations = scope.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know I could have routes like that! However would you be able to explain what the .unscoped does for the Reservation Model? I would highly appreciate it. The rest I understand.

Comment: You know what, I was using it in sort of an off-label way to guarantee we're working with a query-ish object, but both `Reservation` and the result of `where` respond to `all`, so we don't need it. Its actual purpose is to remove any `default_scope`s you may have set on the model.